# Error checking whether there is a result in table

Tags: php, mysql

So I am building a table `session` :

## `session`:

```
session_name | *Text*
session_number | *auto_increment*
```

I want to check whether there is a `session_name` result already in the table and if there isn't add it with a unique session_number then create a session with that number and if there **is** add the session_number to a session:

**attempt**:

```
session_start();
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
}
$name = ucwords(strtolower($_SESSION['name']));

$method = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_name = '$name'";
$resulty = mysql_query($con, $method);
//where $con is the connection to my database
if(mysql_num_rows($resulty) == 0) {
    //not found
     $sql="INSERT INTO session (session_name)

     VALUES

     ('$name')";

}
    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_name = '$name'");
    
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; 
echo $row[1]; // not sure which one is the session_number
mysqli_close($con);
```

---

First of all I am getting the errors

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
```

How come?

---

And also how can I then store the session_number to another session?

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` functions, so it's really hard to tell which function you want to use. If your DB connection is `mysqli_*` then you need to switch all your functions to the same. Plus, `ob_start();` goes on top of `session_start();` --- by the looks of your passing connection first in `$resulty = mysql_query($con, $method);` it's obvious that you're using `mysqli_*` --- It's one or the other, you can't use both. This `expects parameter 1 to be resource` should have been a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it reversed,the `$query` is the first parameter, the `$con` object is the second parameter

```
$method = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_name = '$name'";
$resulty = mysql_query($method, $con);
```

please upgrade to [mysqli_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score -1):

Your second error is caused by your first.

Your call to mysql_query should look like

```
$resulty = mysql_query($method);
```

Comment: I have done that and it says it can't connect to MySQL

Comment: tried calling [mysql_connect()](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) ?

Comment: Yes that was the `$con = mysql_connect()`

Comment: get rid of the `$con`?